# Filling area of multiple contour plots that satisfies a condition in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, 3d, contour

I have a 3D data, the x and y axis are angles and the Z axis is output. so the data is like this: [angle1 x angle2 x Z] ... I have multiple Z values at different conditions as well. Let's assume different Z values for 10 different conditions.

I want to plot a 3D contour of all the Z values overlaid on top of each other and at the same time fill the areas of each contour where Z<=-1 with a desired color ... How is that possible in MATLAB?

I found a way to overlay all the Z values on top of each other using a single color and contour command but I cannot find any way to fill the areas of Z<=-1 ... I realized that in contour command, MATLAB actually fill the whole graph with colors, so "hold on" command does not work here!

Here is an example image I want to create

[image: a]

Below is the example I could create but I cannot create the colored plot

[image]

Comment: Could you show some sample data? And show the code you used to plot your data, but was not the result you were looking for. See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I use the following code to draw my plot but I cannot create the colors

cmap = [0 0 0;0 0 1];
[C,hContour]=contour(height,angle, [-1 inf],'ShowText','off','LineWidth', 2);